# SPRING @RestController: Passing Cookie to a Service from Every Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies

I have a `@RestController` in which every method needs to pass a (WebSSO) cookie down to a service. The service in turn uses the cookie for authentication. I am autowiring the service bean in controller. The service has a setter `setCredentials(String webSSOCookie)`. One easy way is to call this setter in every method. I would like to do it better way;  for instance using `HandlerInterceptor`. However the `HandlerInterceptor` does not have access to the controller (and hence its members) - am I right?

In `jersey` I could use `filter`. How do I achieve it in SPRING?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/documents")
public class ECMRestController {

    @Autowired
    public ECMService ecmService;   

    @RequestMapping(value="/{documentId}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteDocument(@RequestParam("documentId") String documentId) throws IllegalArgumentException, HttpClientErrorException {
         // I could get and pass the cookie to ecmService in every method.
         // ecmService.setCredentials(webSSOCookieObtainedfromRequest);
         // However I don't want to do it that way.
         ecmService.deleteDocument(documentId);
    }

   // Other REST Methods that need to pass the cookie in the same way.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can request the SecurityContextHolder to query the current Authentication that you had customized in a filter.

```
MyCustomAuth auth = (MyCustomAuth) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
auth.getCookie();
```

or you can just use ThreadLocal in a context that can be retrieve from anywhere:

```
public class CookieContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Cookie> COOKIE = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static final CookieContext INSTANCE = new CookieContext();

    public void setCookie(Cookie value) {
        COOKIE.set(value);
    }

    public Cookie getCookie() {
        return COOKIE.get();
    }

    public static CookieContext getContext() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}



public class CookieInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         Object handler) throws Exception {
        CookieContext context = CookieContext.getContext();
        context.setCookie(request.getCookies()[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need the security principle. I need the cookie to pass onto the service. My REST API authenticates the caller (by the way of WebSSO). The resulting cookie needs to be passed to a service, which will 'authorize' the caller. Actually, its not about security or cookie, its about ability to modify the Controller's member in Interceptor.

Comment: Just store it in your authentication object. But i'm gessing something wrong with your design. You should use role.

Comment: What is your "guess" about something being wrong about the design? There is a downstream service that needs a cookie to be sent to it. My Rest needs to obtain the cookie (which it can very well do) and send it with every method. I can send the cookie with every method, but that is not how I want to do it. There should be a better way; i.e. in Interceptor or using AOP. Just that I don't know yet. I don't believe your post answers that.

Comment: So just get the security context set the authentication with your own implementation that contains the cookie that you can retrieve from anywhere in your code. Or Create your own context using ThreadLocal. And yes you can do use an Aspect, Interceptor or a filter.